# SQL execution plan has sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I'm using the AdventureWorks database, ran the below query:

```
-- 9
select *
from Production.ProductModel
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from Production.Product
    where Production.Product.ProductModelID = Production.ProductModel.ProductModelID
);
```

I got back 9 records, which is correct, but when I checked the execution plan I saw there was a Sort done:

[image]

[image]

Why was a sort done? Is it coming from the inner query?

Comment: Maybe to find the exists - do you have an index on `ProductModelID`? Note "Paste The Plan" is a better way to share an execution plan.

Comment: I agree an index on `ProductModelID` is needed, it is necessary anyway for the (presumable) foreign key, otherwise inserts and deletes will be really slow. Side note: you should use short table aliases. Three part column names is deprecated, and hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

> why was a sort done?

SQL Server decided to implement the *exists* check using a *merge* join - the left anti semi join in the plan.

A merge join requires both inputs to be sorted - hence it can do a single pass and efficiently match similarly sorted inputs.

SQL Server decided the additional cost of sorting the ProductModelID in order to implement the merge join would be worth the performance advantage.

You could force SQL Server to use a different join operator using a query *option hint* and examine the execution plan to determine if the optimizer was correct, eg `option(loop join);`

Comment: Great explanation, but for the number of rows involved, I doubt an option hint would make any difference at all. I would even be surprised if a loop (which goes against all sql principles) would take much longer

Comment: True and I don't have this database to investigate, you likely won't see any measurable difference but the plan might indicate if SQL Server had to read any more, or fewer pages, which is normally a good guide - there's not enough info in the image provided, ie no actual rows read etc, in order to make any better judgement.

Comment: Create an index `CREATE INDEX Product_ProductModelId_IX ON Product (ProductModelId);`. That way sorting will be done up-front for you at the expense of a little disk space.